# Как выбрать конкретный элемент Html если у него такой же класс как и другого элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, классы

Проблема вот в чем, путём  `document.getElementsByClassName('class');` я получаю доступ к первому элементу с классом "class". Но мне нужно выбрать второй, как это сделать?

```html
<div class="class123">
  <span class="class"></span>
</div>
<div class="class321">
  <span class="class"></span>//этот нужно выбрать
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('class')[1];` ?

Comment: @splash58 не работает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ofa2u517/

Comment: @МаксимБуяков работает

Comment: лучше уже по id выбирать, так надежнее

Comment: А какова конечная цель?

Comment: если надо достать 2рой, то вариант предложеный splash58 работает, во всех других вариантах, нужно уточнить когда именно и при каких условиях нужно получить елемент

Answer (score 0):

```js
// методом document.getElementsByClassName('class'); получаем не первый элемент
// данного класса, а все...
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('classs'));

// первый мы получаем методом document.querySelector('.class')
console.log(document.querySelector('.classs'));

// что бы получить нужный элемент способов куча...  все завист от для чего и где

// если у элемента нет уникального идентификатора как в данном случае
// то просто по индексу 
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('classs')[1]);

// или можно ему присвоить ID уже без индекса получить его по ID
console.log(document.getElementById('vtoroi'));
//или так
console.log(document.querySelector('#vtoroi'));

// если это какая нибудь функция в которой должен делать что-то именно второй 
//элемент то так

// надо прокрутить в цикле 
var classs = document.getElementsByClassName('classs')

for (let i = 0; i < classs.length; i++) {
  classs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // и тут условие 
    if (classs[i] == classs[1]) {
      this.style.background = 'red';
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="class123">
  <span class="classs">Первый. Кликни по мне</span>
</div>
<div class="class321">
  <span class="classs" id="vtoroi">Второй. Кликни по мне</span>
  <!--этот нужно выбрать-->
</div>
```